# Restructuring a GIT project

Tags: git, github

I got an existing project from GIT and made several changes to it as part of code restructuring and cleanup. Added few stuff and moved few folders around and deleted some, and now i want to add it to GIT as a separate new project that folks can start using. how will i go about doing this?

Comment: can you clarify what "add it to GIt as a separate new project" means? If you need to start from pristine history, just create a new repo, clone it on your computer, copy over the relevant files (from the directory of restructured project), git add/commit/push would just fit.Otherwise if you want to keep history, just add a new remote and push to it, where this remote points to a new pristine repository.

Answer (score 2):

You mean as a new project without history? You can either init a new repository, copy over the files and make an initial commit, or you can use `git checkout --orphan` and then commit, pushing that new branch to some remote repo where you want to publish it.

Comment: yes, essentially want to move a bunch of existing repositories under a new single repository.

Comment: Then maybe subtree merge is what you after.

Answer (score 0):

I've bumped into a similar question recently, so leaving it here with a hope that it will help somebody.
The problem was with restructuring a highly active git project. Restructuring itself took lots of time, while lots of new commits were added every day. It could lead to lots of merging problems. The solution was to create a bash script, which restructures the repo and then apply it to the latest version. It allows the team to work on other issues and on restructuring simultaneously without merging conflicts at all. [I wrote about it more here](http://bdshadow.blogspot.com/2018/09/restructuring-highly-active-git-project.html)